# Chrome crashes with Selenium in robot Framework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Our team are working on a automation project with Chrome and we are facing a problem regarding to Chrome.

We have like 1000 scripts with so many test suite, each test suite setup is opening Chrome Webdriver process and at the end - Suite teardown will close and end the Chrome Webdriver.

But sometime, Chrome (or Chrome driver) crashes with 2 common reasons (I didnt captured the correct issue but when I face it again, I will report here).

This make the other suites fail, because they cannot open Chrome again.

About this issue, have anyone dealed with it before? Could you please give me a suggestion to resolve it?

Comment: How can someone help you without Html or code ? Need more information

Comment: couple of things, robot framework in java or python? which version of robot framework? which version of chrome binary? which version of chrome ?

Comment: I have the same issue, it seems sometimes Robot session gets frozen and opening browser gets frozen.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your setup? For example how many machines are involved. Do you use a single instance of Robot Framework to run all 1,000 tests or do you use Pabot. Is the browser running on the same machine as Robot Framework or do you use a Selenium Grid solution?

Comment: For me it's single instance, running RF ver 3.0 with approx 1300 test cases.

Comment: Is it only the Chrome browser that is the issue, or is also the webdriver still runnning? I.e. ChromeDriver.exe. In any case it won't hurt to also run a command to kill the driver and browser at Suite Teardown: `taskkill /F /im name.exe`

Comment: Not sure if that would kill the party if we run pybot with 6 simultaneously running tests? I know this is not the issue, it sometimes happens to me only when I run RIDE...

Comment: As highlighted by the original poster, it's a single instance where browser and RF are running on the same instance. So, there would only be 1 running test at any given time. Now, whether this is a good setup is a different matter, but if this setup performs well enough for the original poster then this taskkill approach would help.